How to separate date and time into 2 new columns in R
I want to split the date&time column into two columns
I have used
print( format(as.POSIXct(data), format = "%H:%M"))

but ran into an error as it did not make changed to the actual DF
What I have:
enter image description here
What I want:
enter image description here
I have used
print( format(as.POSIXct(data), format = "%H:%M")) 

but ran into an error as it did not make changes to the actual DF.

What we see is a picture of the data in Excel. When you load it into R, it could take a variety of forms (e.g. character, numeric, date, datetime) depending on how you load it. Can you edit your question and share the output of running dput(head(data)) so we can understand what format it's in and try out potential solutions?

in R its best to maintain the date and time as one column ie TIDY data. Having it in different columns is UNTIDY. Why would you want it to be in different columns? dealing with time with no date is impractical unless of course you only care about one day. Anyway you can still separate them using strCapture, mutate, separate_wider_Delim etc

In general in R, taking data and running code on it will produce output that reflects that code, but without changing the original object. So running format(data, ...) will not change the actual DF. You might want data <- format(data, ...)

Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See this Meta and a relevant xkcd. Can you post sample data in dput format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of dput(head(data)).

I full agree with prior recommendations that in R it is generally better to keep date and time together, but I've also run into situations (admittedly specific and rare) where it is really necessary. Assuming (perhaps a large assumption) that you are in one of these situations, then you can use substring to separate the date/time strings into date and time strings. Realize that all you have at this time are strings, you have no real timestamps in R, unless/until you call as.POSIXct on the combined string or as.Date on the date (and "something", undef atm) on the time columns.

I want them to be in different columns. Even if it is untidy to some that is the request

Okay, how about the other requests? I don't relish transcribing data from an image to something usable on the console. If that data is saved into a CSV, at a minimum you can paste a few lines of that CSV file into a [code block]. Even if not, you can load that file into R into a frame, then (as already stated twice) paste that data into your question.

I used separate which is a part of TIDYVERSE

This is the ANSWER
DF<-separate(DF,
col=COL1,
into=c("date","time"),
sep = " ")

You have used backticks for your COL1 column? Does that mean your COL1 column name has a leading space? If not, use quotes instead of backticks. If so, having a leading space is not a great idea.

I’m confused where do you see backticks?

Where it says  COL1.

I don’t see backtick marks on my version it’s just COL1 the name, nothing around it

Click "Edit" and you will see them. As to my question, is there supposed to be a space in the column name?

I see what you are saying. No there is no space and no space when I put it into my R. When you try to edit , it does give a space and backtick marks. Its weird.
